# Reload widget with AJAX

Tags: widgets, ajax, query

I created a widget with additional settings fields (orderby etc.) that displays users using `new WP_User_Query( $args )`.

I also created a `follow user` button. I was able to successfully use ajax to update the database, show custom message and more.

Now I've reached the point where I want to update the list of followers inside the widget (with AJAX) once `follow user` button has been clicked. but I'm not sure how to tackle this one.

Output of the widget is placed inside a `container` class, so it will be easy to target this class inside the ajax `success` function.

```
<div class="follow-me-container"> 
<table>...</table>
</div>
```

Based on online tutorials, I've to completely rebuilt the query inside the `wp_ajax_` function. However, the widget uses predefined settings which I want to keep.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us your php `wp_ajax_` function and js?

Comment: I haven't started adding the code that is relevant to target the widget/container class.  The code I have so far is only related to updating the database, custom message, buttons, etc.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the old Admin AJAX API and not the new REST API endpoints?

Comment: Not really, I've been reading up a lot about using AJAX in WP, so I started to give it a try. Is AJAX outdated?